# Cloud Firestore Security Rules - access properties in arrays of objects

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Is it possible to access document property values contained in arrays of objects?

I've been working through the excellent [Angular Firebase guide on Security Rules](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/firestore-security-rules-guide/) - in which document keys are used to satisfy access requirements. Here's an example:

Simple User document

```
name: 'a user',
roles: {
  admin: true,
  editor: true
}
```

Security rule

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
      function getUserData() {
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/accounts/$(request.auth.uid)).data
      }
      function userHasRole(role) {
        return getUserData().roles[role] == true;
      }
      match /<some_path>/ {
        allow read, write: if userHasRole(editor);

    }
  }
}
```

My user document structure is slightly more complicated though as the application has different modules, each with their own roles. For example:

Complex User document

```
name: 'a user',
roles:[
  {
    feature: 'feature 1',
    role: 'admin'
  },
  {
    feature: 'feature 2',
    role: 'editor'
  }
]
```

With my user document structured like this, is it possible to access the 'role' value of a given feature within the security rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way you've structured your roles is working against your desired outcome.  You really want your `roles` field on the user document to be indexed by key names of all the roles the user may have, more similar to the first example you showed, which makes it easy to look up if a user has a role.

The way you have it now, the rule would have to be able to 1) iterate all the roles, then 2) check to see if each iterated object has a field value for `role` that matches what you want.  Security rules aren't flexible enough to express this logic.